# EF DbContext with Explicitly Implemented properties throws 'ModelValidationException'

Tags: .net, entity-framework, ef-code-first, entity-framework-5, entity-framework-migrations

I have an interface that defines what DbSets should be available to consumers, like this:

```
public interface IMyContext : IDisposable
{
    IDbSet<Regional> Regionals { get; set; }

    IDbSet<Unit> Units { get; set; }

    int SaveChanges();
}
```

We decided on creating this interface to be able to inject any implementations into other classes, which helps with testing for instance.

This was the implementation of it a few minutes ago:

```
public sealed class MyContext : DbContext, IMyContext
{
    public IDbSet<Regional> Regionals { get; set; }

    public IDbSet<Unit> Units { get; set; }
}
```

Very simple stuff.

Today, when working on a few related classes, I decided to convert those properties to explicit implementations, to disallow access if it is not typed to the interface.

```
public sealed class MyContext : DbContext, IMyContext
{
    IDbSet<Regional> IMyContext.Regionals { get; set; }

    IDbSet<Unit> IMyContext.Units { get; set; }
}
```

As soon as I changed that and tried adding a new migration I got an exception:

```
System.Data.Entity.ModelConfiguration.ModelValidationException: One or more validation errors were detected during model generation:

\tSystem.Data.Entity.Edm.EdmEntitySet: Name: The specified name is not allowed: 'MyProject.IMyContext.Regionals'.
\tSystem.Data.Entity.Edm.EdmEntitySet: Name: The specified name is not allowed: 'MyProject.IMyContext.Units'.

   at System.Data.Entity.ModelConfiguration.Edm.EdmModelExtensions.ValidateAndSerializeCsdl(EdmModel model, XmlWriter writer)
   at System.Data.Entity.DbModelBuilder.Build(DbProviderManifest providerManifest, DbProviderInfo providerInfo)
   at System.Data.Entity.DbModelBuilder.Build(DbConnection providerConnection)
   at System.Data.Entity.Internal.LazyInternalContext.CreateModel(LazyInternalContext internalContext)
   at System.Data.Entity.Internal.RetryLazy`2.GetValue(TInput input)
   at System.Data.Entity.Internal.LazyInternalContext.InitializeContext()
   at System.Data.Entity.Internal.LazyInternalContext.get_CodeFirstModel()
   at System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.EdmxWriter.WriteEdmx(DbContext context, XmlWriter writer)
   at System.Data.Entity.Migrations.Extensions.DbContextExtensions.<>c__DisplayClass1.<GetModel>b__0(XmlWriter w)
   at System.Data.Entity.Migrations.Extensions.DbContextExtensions.GetModel(Action`1 writeXml)
   at System.Data.Entity.Migrations.Extensions.DbContextExtensions.GetModel(DbContext context)
   at System.Data.Entity.Migrations.DbMigrator..ctor(DbMigrationsConfiguration configuration, DbContext usersContext)
   at System.Data.Entity.Migrations.DbMigrator..ctor(DbMigrationsConfiguration configuration)
   at System.Data.Entity.Migrations.Design.ToolingFacade.BaseRunner.GetMigrator()
   at System.Data.Entity.Migrations.Design.ToolingFacade.GetPendingMigrationsRunner.RunCore()
   at System.Data.Entity.Migrations.Design.ToolingFacade.BaseRunner.Run()
One or more validation errors were detected during model generation:

\tSystem.Data.Entity.Edm.EdmEntitySet: Name: The specified name is not allowed: 'MyProject.IMyContext.Regionals'.
\tSystem.Data.Entity.Edm.EdmEntitySet: Name: The specified name is not allowed: 'MyProject.IMyContext.Units'.
```

What is happening here? It seems EF Migration is not able to deduce the EntitySet names anymore from the properties, because they are now explicit implementations. If I use the `OnModelCreating` method to override the entityset names it works:

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{
    modelBuilder.Entity<Unit>().HasEntitySetName("Units");
    modelBuilder.Entity<Regional>().HasEntitySetName("Regionals");
}
```

I would obviously want to avoid that though and use the property names automatically like before. Is this a bug in EF or is it intended behavior?

The environment is using EF 5 with .Net 4.

**Update**

I've confirmed my suspicions about reflection returning the property name differently for explicitly implemented properties. I've done a simple test using LINQPad and here it is:

```
public interface ITest
{
    string Prop1 {get; set;}
    string Prop2 {get; set;}
}

public class Test : ITest
{
    string ITest.Prop1 {get; set;}
    public string Prop2 {get; set;}
}

void Main()
{
    var properties = typeof(Test).GetProperties(BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.NonPublic);
    Console.WriteLine(String.Join(", ", properties.Select(_=>_.Name)));
}
```

The binding flags there are needed because the explicit property implementation is internal, but the implicit one is public.

Here is the output:

```
UserQuery.ITest.Prop1, Prop2
```

I did not look at EF's code, but I would imagine it is using this kind of reflection to build the entity set names. I would consider this a bug, personally. Would still like to hear what the EF people think of this.

Comment: Just a reminder: whenever you answer someone's question, that person is automatically notified of your response, so there is no need to notify again via a comment like this. This would admittedly be useful if I was not the author of this question though.